# How to get more continuity in regression forest output

Tags: distributions, random-forest, cart, hyperparameter

I am using a regression forest.

What I have noticed when I plot the quantile distribution of the forest's output is that over a long stretch of quantiles (e.g. $\tau \in [0.1,0.3]$), the output will all assume the identical number. I am guessing this comes from the sparsity of my response variable and the distributional characteristics of my features (and also the shallowness of my trees).

What are some hyperparameter settings (or other approaches) that I could use to introduce more continuity into the forest's output? The best case would be a linear model-esque output. My goal is to achieve this without wounding generalisation (which may not be possible). Some wounding of generalisation is acceptable (i.e. suboptimal hyperparameter settings) if it means I can use the model to make decisions more easily.